# MongoDB updateMany, dynamic filter field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When using the .updateMany(filter, update, option). How can I set a dynamic filter field for every document?

I have an array of documents like this:

```
[
    {
        time: 1,
        data: []
    },
    {
        time: 2,
        data: []
    },
    {
        time: 3,
        data: []
    }
]
```

Each with a unique timestamp. In case the timestamp already exists, the corresponding document should be updated with the new data but if the time doesn't exists, create a new document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

But as it seems, .updateMany() only allows a static filter field. Like this

```
Candles.updateMany({time: 'someStaticTime'}, documents);
```

while I would prefer something like this

```
Candles.updateMany({time: $currentInsertingDocument.time}, documents);
```

Is this possible without looping over each document seperate??

Comment: Could you clarify what you want?   I read it as "If the time already exists, the doc should be updated, else create new time" which strikes me as saying set all time fields to a new timestamp, no?

Comment: I updated the question. And yes correct indeed, its an array of documents, the index key in a way is the unique timestamp. So if a document comes by that has an already existing timestamp, that document should be updated, otherwise create new document.. But to accomplish that I would need to filter on the time field as a dynamic field, changing on each document that its looping internally

Comment: I think you should use `Bulk` API: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/

Comment: @Michael I fixed it with Bulk indeed.. If you make it a post I will set it as answer

Comment: @DutchKevv you are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Mongo's [Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert)